# openssl / libressl ocsp responder missing response for expired/revoked certificates

Tags: openssl, ocsp, libressl

For some reason, an OpenSSL OCSP responder doesn't seem to deliver any responses for expired or revoked certificates. For valid certificates, everything is fine.

Tested this on LibreSSL 2.2.7 (on MacOS). For reference, I also tested this on the very old OpenSSL 0.9.8f, same issue.

**Setup**

File index.txt (Fields are tab separated):

```
V   20991231235959Z     32F31   unknown /CN=valid01
V   20991231235959Z     32F32   unknown /CN=valid02
V   20991231235959Z     32F33   unknown /CN=valid03
E   20171231235959Z     32F34   unknown /CN=expired01
E   20171231235959Z     32F35   unknown /CN=expired02
E   20171231235959Z     32F36   unknown /CN=expired03
R   20171231235959Z 20160631235959Z 32F37   unknown /CN=revoked01
R   20171231235959Z 20160631235959Z 32F38   unknown /CN=revoked02
R   20171231235959Z 20160631235959Z 32F39   unknown /CN=revoked03
V   20991231235959Z     32F3A   unknown /CN=valid04
```

File index.txt.attr:

```
unique_subject = yes
```

File ca.pem:

```
(Please create your own, self-signed ca with key)
```

Start OCSP responder using

```
openssl ocsp -index index.txt -port 8084 -rkey ca.pem -rsigner ca.pem -CA ca.pem -text -resp_no_certs
```

**Test**

Query valid certificate (no problem here):

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer ca.pem -serial 0x32f31 -url http://localhost:8084 -noverify
0x32f31: good
    This Update: Sep 27 12:46:06 2018 GMT
```

Query expired or revoked certficate (misings response):

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer ca.pem -serial 0x32f36 -url http://localhost:8084 -noverify
0x32f36: ERROR: No Status found.
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. OpenSSL seems to require the timestamps in the index file to be in two-digit year form instead of four-digits. Year 2000 problem anyone? Apparently not.